# Is it safe to delete the "InetPub" folder?

Tags: iis-7

Does anyone know if deleting the InetPub folder will hurt IIS or anything related?

I am using IIS 7.

Comment: What's the problem with Inetpub if you can have your web root anywhere, inclusive in a network path? Is like if you want to remove your Apache or Tomcat folder with these web servers! Strange behavior!

Comment: who wants to drill into inetpub\wwroot...wtf is that for?  makes no sense.  How about just c:\www\applicationname1  c:\www\applicationname2  simple, makes sense, not lame.

Comment: I mean I think it's time MS get rid of old names that don't convey intent.

Comment: Related: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2752331/guidance-for-relocation-of-iis-7-0-and-iis-7-5-content-directories

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IIS will create it again AFAIK.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you go into the IIS configuration and change the default location from %SystemDrive%\InetPub to %SystemDrive%\www for each of the services (web, ftp) there shouldn't be any problems.  Of course, you can't protect against other applications that might install stuff into that directory by default, instead of checking the configuration.

My recommendation?  **Don't change it** -- it's not that hard to live with, and it reduces the confusion level for the next person who has to administrate the machine.

Answer (score 5):

If you [reconfigure IIS7](http://forums.iis.net/t/1073841.aspx) to use your new location, then there's no problem. Just test that the new location is working, before deleting the old location.

> **Change IIS7 Inetpub path**
>
> - Open  %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config and search for
>
> %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot
>
> - Change the path.

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete the folder or you will create a registry problem.  However, if you do not want to use IIS, search the web for turning it off.  You might want to check out "www.blackviper.com" because he lists all Operating System "services" (Not "Computer Services" - both are in Administrator Tools) with extra information for what you can and cannot disable to change to manual.  If I recall correctly, he had some IIS info and how to turn it off.

Answer (score -3):

it is safe to delete the inetpub it is only a cache.

Comment: it's not a cache - it's the [default] base root of your website